# Почему счётчик (Google Analytics, Я.Метрика) рекомендуется располагать в начале страницы до остальных скриптов?

Tags: javascript, html

Вот например Я.Метрика пишет:

> Рекомендуем разместить его как можно ближе к началу страницы — от
>   этого зависит полнота и корректность подсчета данных.

По логике надо думать о пользователях, а не о счётчиках.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что если с вашим скриптом будет какая-то проблема или баг или он просто будет долго грузится, то скрипт метрики может вообще не загрузится, или пользователь уйдёт со страницы раньше его загрузки, а значит, вы вообще не узнаете что пользователь был на вашем сайте, т.е. данные будут не точными.

Answer (score 0):

Для точных подсчетов  счетчики ставить нужно вниз . как и любой js  скрип ! 
последовательность загрузки . HTML CSS  Metriks  и после все остальные  js  файлы.
В данном случай счетчик будит  считать всех тех кто дождался  загрузки страницы .
 а всех тех кто  отвалился раньше  не посчитает . И показатель отказа будит меньше. Т е в случай поведенческого фактора  это будит  незначительный + к сео сайта .Ну и что говорить П.С  сами рекомендуют так делать.

Comment: Где рекомендуют? Можно ссылочку.

Comment: Это загрузчик библиотеки счетчиков и часто аггрегатор очереди (чтобы события можно было собрать до того, как основной код загрузится)

Comment: @zb' Вы ошиблись сообщением. Я про другое тут спросил.

Comment: @Khipster а я и не вам а на ответ, человек советует глупость.

Comment: Яндекс рекомендует в вверху (между head и ли в body)